# Extract Directory Names from Dynamic File Paths in Python

Tags: python, regex, regex-group, os.path

Is there a way in Python to extract each file directory and the file in a windows file path either through the use of `REGEX` and `group()` or `os.path`?

I'm dealing with the file paths that have varying amount of directories, so one line could be `D:\dir1\file.txt` while the next could be `Z:\dir1\dir2\dir3\dir4\dir5\file.txt`, so I wonder if there is even a way to do this with `REGEX` or a built in function in Python when there are varying amounts of `\` in the text I'm searching.

Any insight would be helpful, even if it's just the bitter truth that it can't be done.

After Edit:

I'm trying to extract the directory names in between the `\` and the final `file.txt` and write each `dir` or `file` to it's own column in an output text file.

My desired output for the above two lines would be:

```
 col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|col6
 dir1|dir2|dir3|dir4|dir5|file.txt
 dir1|    |    |    |    |file.txt
```

I know `os.path` has a lot of good built in functions, but after reading this site: https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html, I don't think any of them are doing what I'm trying to do.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to extract?  That is, given your second example (`Z:\dir1\dir2\dir3\dir4\dir5\file.txt`), what exactly do you want?

Comment: What do you mean by `extract each file directory and the file`? Do you want to store them separately in a list? Can you show desired output?

Comment: @Kamehameha I want to take each directory name between the backslashes `\` as well as the file name and write each element to it's own column by having a bar `|` in between the `dir` names and file name. I will write them to the output file `|` delimited. The desired output is describe in the edited question above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can separate fileName and directory by using:

```
splitFilePath = filePath.rsplit (']\', 1)
directory = splitFilePath [0]
fileName = splitFilePath [1]
```

You can get all chunks separated by '\' by using:

```
chunks = filePath.split (r'\')
```

You can then take out particular chunks by using slicing and glue subsets of them together using join.

Using the columns as you added in your edited question assumes you know your longest path to determine the number of columns:

- Split using split function as explained above
- Find length of longest list
- Insert empty strings in all lists but the longest before the last element to make the lists equal length
- Join them using '|' using join function

In response to your comment:

Running the following program

```
filePath = r'E:\dir1\Logs\dir2\1998-12-23\message.txt'
splitFilePath = filePath.rsplit ('\\', 1)
directory = splitFilePath [0]
fileName = splitFilePath [1]
print directory
print fileName
```

gives as output

```
E:\dir1\Logs\dir2\1998-12-23
message.txt
```

So '\\' rather than '\' in the rsplit.

Comment: When i run `filename2 = splitFilePath[1]` against the string `E:\dir1\Logs\dir2\1998-12-23\message.txt` I get the following error: `IndexError: list index out of range`. Also, the regex for search a `\`` is `(r'\\')`

Comment: I've corrected and tested the example, don't use r'\\' but just '\\'.

Comment: Awesome! It works and I got the following output when I `print(directory.split("\\")`: `['E:', 'dir1', 'Logs', 'dir2', '1998-12-23']`.